# Is Kestrel completely in-process?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, kestrel-http-server

I have created a C# console application (using the simple console application template) and I am using Kestrel to host an HTTP service using Web API. My question is: is Kestrel in-process? Can I be sure that no other process related to IIS or anything else will be used? There doesn't seem to be any documentation in Microsoft's site to confirm this.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseKestrel(options =>
        {
            options.ListenLocalhost(6001, listenOptions => { });
        })
        .Build()
        .Run();
}
```

Comment: Given that Kestrel is cross-platform, and IIS isn't, how do you think that would work out?

Comment: are you referring to AspNetCoreHostingModel ?

Answer (score 2):

Kestrel is a fully managed webserver written in C# and runs in process yes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Kestrel is open source and cross-platform, meaning, it does not depend on Windows, nor does it use any kind of Windows service or process.

Comment: Is it not using the kernel level HTTP driver?

Comment: @TomTom No, it implements its own HTTP server. It does not rely on http.sys

Comment: As @canton7 said, Kestrel and HTTP.sys are two alternative implementations, HTTP.sys is Windows (but not IIS) specific.