# What exactly is the ASP.NET Core 5 host?

Tags: asp.net-core

After the build, inside the bin folder, there are 2 main files
`{AppName}.exe` and `{AppName}.dll`, what I understand is `AppName.dll` is the actual compiled application code and `AppName.exe` is the host which hosts the app inside Kestrel.

My question: is this `.exe` due to the `Program.cs`, and is it the one that acts as a worker process under which our application runs because we get the process name as application name for ASP.NET Core 5 and not dotnet (`dotnet.exe`) anymore.

Answer (score 3):

`{AppName}.exe` is an [executable file that is used to run the application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build). It acts as the host and serves as the entry point for your ASP.NET Core application.

When you execute `{AppName}.exe`, here's what happens:

- It loads the compiled application code from `{AppName}.dll` and starts execution from the entry point defined in `Program.cs`.
- It sets up and runs the **host** such as ASP.NET's [WebApplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/webapplication?view=aspnetcore-8.0) or [Generic Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host?tabs=appbuilder) ( this *host* is the answer to your title question).

  - Host builder gets created and is used to set up services. For eg:

    ```cs
    var builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args); // In console apps, worker services etc.
    // OR
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args); // In web apps
    ```
  - Host is built.

    ```cs
    // The host and console app are not the same thing - the host is just a part that runs inside your console application.
    using IHost host = builder.Build(); // In console apps, worker services etc.
    // OR
    var app = builder.Build(); // In web apps
    ```
  - Host is run which essentially runs the app. For eg:

    ```cs
    await host.RunAsync(); // In console apps, worker services etc.
    // OR
    app.Run(); // In web apps
    ```
- Host starts configured services. (In web apps, [Kestrel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-8.0#get-started) is started as a hosted service under [`{AppName}.exe` process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61608221/8644294).)

**Note:** You can also run console apps without using the Generic host. But this way you won't be able to use dependency injection, logging, and other services. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration#alternative-hosting-approach)

---

> My question: is this `.exe` due to the `Program.cs`

Yes, the `{AppName}.exe` file is created when you compile your project, and its behaviour is defined in part by the configuration outlined in `Program.cs`.

> is it the one that acts as a worker process under which our
> application runs

The `{AppName}.exe` file doesn’t act as a worker process; it serves as the host process for your application.

Answer (score 0):

`AppName.exe` is not the host. The exe is an executable that can be used to run the application, if the project type is an executable targeting .NET Core 3.0 or later. More about details you can refer to [dotnet build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build) command.

The ASP.NET Core project templates use Kestrel by default. In *Program.cs*, the ConfigureWebHostDefaults method calls UseKestrel:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        //use Kestrel 
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

And below are some helpful links about host topic:

[Kestrel web server implementation in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[In-process hosting with IIS and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/in-process-hosting?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[Out-of-process hosting with IIS and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/out-of-process-hosting?view=aspnetcore-5.0)